# Is there a setting to add a suffix and prefix to a list(integer) field like there was in Drupal 6?

Tags: 7, entities, migrations

I am in the process of migrating a Drupal 6 site to 7. Several of my content types have a field called "Rating" which was an integer field in D6 that used a `<select>` to choose a value 1-10.

In the process of migrating to D7 this field was converted to a list(integer) field. On the old site I was able to add a suffix of "/10" to this value in the field's settings so the field would always render as "#/10". However, in Drupal 7 there is no longer a place to set this suffix on the field's setting page.

Does this setting exist anymore for this field type? If not, do I have any options for adding this suffix outside of creating a custom "field--field-rating.tpl.php" template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Simple Field Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter) module, see the below screenshot

[image]

Which allows site administrators to easily control the display of
field values with following features

> - Prepend the field value with specified text/HTML
> - Append the field value with specified text/HTML
> - Reverse the Field Value
> - Trim the Field Value
> - Convert the field value to lowercase letters
> - Convert the field value to uppercase letters
> - Convert the first character of the field value to uppercase
> - Convert the first character of each word in the field value to uppercase (7.x-1.x-dev)
> - Replace some characters with some other characters in the field value (7.x-1.x-dev)
> - Link the field value to node(7.x-2.x-dev)